# Compiling C program in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

When I try to run my C program in eclipse, a message pops up saying : "Launch failed. Binary not found". Is this because I'm missing a compiler or is there some other reason? From what I read online, Eclipse does have a built in compiler so I thought compiling shouldn't be a problem. How do I make this problem disappear?

Answer (score 0):

I hope there's is not much data for answer, but looks like somebody have got similar mistake in wrote about it on official Eclipse forum. [[Here]](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=824895)

> I got the same problem and followed all the step but was getting the same error,  Then i selected "project" from the menu and clicked
>   "Build All", my binaries generated in my project and i can able to
>   execute the file.
>
> Try , hope it will help you

Comment: Also, why do you use an Eclipse as framework for working with C. Even Code::Blocks OR DEV-CPP (Free softwar) looks great for C.

Comment: If you still want to use an Eclipse as text editor, I should advice to you use GCC compiler and console commands `g++ yourprogramm.c -o programName`